# How to verify parametr from request URL? (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, katalon-recorder

I am on that page:

```
http://localhost:8080/login?error=true
```

**How can i check is `error` variable contains value `true`?**

[image]

Here is my failed try:

[image]

Error:

```
[info] Executing: | assertAttribute | error | true |
[info] Wait until the element is found
[error] Implicit Wait timed out after 10000ms
[error] Element erro not found
```

---

I am using:

1. ***Selenium IDE*** ---> *3.16.1*
2. ***Katalon Recorder*** ---> *4.0.0*
3. ***Chrome 64-bit*** ---> *79.0.3945.130*

   ---

I am newbie in the world of testing. Can someone help? :(

Answer (score 1):

the code below will work

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://localhost:8080/login')
currentURL = driver.current_url
x = currentURL.find('error=true')
if x == -1:
    print("error=true")
```

Comment: hmm how can i implement such a code when i am using Selenium IDE? :<

Answer (score 0):

`Assert Attribute` command is used for check of attributes of DOM element. So here you need to use js:

```
execute script | var url = window.location.href; return /error=true/.test(url); |flag
assert | flag | true
```